# Ansible and fact dependent variables

Tags: ansible

Can an inventory variable in Ansible be dependent on a fact?

Namely, I have a variable in `group_vars/all/cars.yml` that I would like to set to a value dependent on `ansible_fqdn`. Like:

> ---
>
> link: "http://{{ ansible_fqdn }}:8070/api"

I have tried that and it sometimes seems to work and sometimes not, giving me the literal ansible_fqdn expression without substituting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible **group_vars** files are designed to define variables with corresponding values that may be dependent of other **variables** defined previously. As such they act as **constants** that your **playbook** can use based on some conditions (OS distro, OS version, ...).
The facts are relative to the nodes your playbook is acting on, they can be used inside **playbooks** but are not available in the **group_vars** files.

Now, back to your use-case, it's possible to define fact **dynamically** in a playbook and use it in your tasks:

```
- name: define the link fact based on ansible_fqdn
  set_fact: link="http://{{ ansible_fqdn }}:8070/api"

- debug: msg="link = {{ link }}"

- debug: var=link
```

Please have a look [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) for more details.